# What does mean this instruction in postscript?

Tags: postscript

I'm new to this language but I do not understand what does mean this instruction in postscript.
 I'm quite familiar with Polish Notation, but still this instruction does not make sense to me.

`/doStartGroupFile where { pop doStartGroupFile } if`

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not too hard. The `where` operator is described on page 718 of the PostScript Language Reference Manual. It takes a single parameter, the 'key' off the stack and searches all current dictionaries on the dictionary stack (starting with the topmost, or current, dictionary) for a dictionary which contains that key.

If it finds a dictionary which contains that key it pushes a reference to the dictionary on the operand stack, and then pushes a boolean 'true' on the operand stack.

If it doesn't find a dictionary which contains the key it pushes a boolean 'false' on the operand stack.

So `/doStartGroupFile where` looks for the existence of a dictionary containing the key '/doStartGroupFile'

The next element (from '{' to '}') is an executable array, so we just bundle that up and put it on the operand stack.

So, depending on the result of the 'where operator the operand stack will either contain:

> {} true
>   -dict-

Or:

> {} false

Next up is the `if` operator, you can find this defined on page 607 of the PLRM. The `if` operator consumes two operands from the operand stack, a procedure and a boolean.

If the boolean is true, then it executes the procedure, if its false, it simply discards it.

So if 'doStartGroupFile' was found we execute the procedure, if it wasn't, we discard it. Assuming it was found the operand stack while we execute the procedure will simply contain the reference to the dictionary where we found doStartGroupFile.

The procedure is declared as `{pop doStartGroupFile}`, and that first removes the top element from the operand stack (so it discards the reference to the dictionary) and then resolves doStartGroupFile. No idea what doStartGroupFile is, but I'd guess its an executable procedure defined elsewhere.

So in summary, the code fragment searches for a definition of 'doStartGroupFile', if it finds one it executes it, otherwise it does nothing.

Simples :-)